# Why does the swift compiler think the closure is trailing?

Tags: swift

I'm attempting to declare a void returning closure and use it immediately following another expression. So I realize the compiler doesn't 'see' the whitespace but why does it think `someFunc` has a closure argument when it clearly doesn't? In other words why is the `;` necessary?

```swift
func someFunc() {

}

func someFunc2() {
    someFunc();

    { arg in
        print("\(arg + 1)")
    }(0)
}
```

When the semicolon is removed xcode gives the error "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments". Is this really according to design?

Comment: Someone else posted the answer, but you can also do `let closure = { arg in ... }` then call `closure(0)`. This will clear the ambiguity.

Comment: Syntax check always comes before any further code analysis. Even `someFunc()` does not take any arguments, the syntax `someFucn(){ }` appears to be passing a closure argument to `someFunc`, hence it fails further code analysis.

Answer (score 0):

`f { /* closure contents here */ }` is the more common form of a trailing closure, but the brackets don't necessarily have to be omitted (in fact, they're necessary if there are other parameters before the closure), which means that `f() { /* closure contents here */ }` is also a valid trailing closure.

Some people like their starting `{` in a new line (I know this is the convention in C#, for example), so this behaviour you're seeing looks like it's meant to accommodate such people.

Answer (score 0):

You say that "I'm attempting to declare a void-returning closure".  but you didn't declare closure in function return

**So the changes are:-**

```
func someFunction() {
    print("Some function is call")
}

func someFunction2() -> ((_ arg: Any) -> Void) {
    someFunction()

    return { arg in
        print("Closure return")
    }
}
```